# How to install Certbot SSL on ec2-instance Linux (Apache Web Server)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I got this problem when I tried to install Certbot on ec2-instance linux (Apache Web Server). I already install PuTTY(to access into instance) and WinSCP (to transfer the file). But when I run some command, refer to AWS guide, it shows the error like below:

```
Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt", line 11, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1378, in main
      return config.func(config, plugins)

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
      packages/certbot/main.py", line 1133, in run certname, lineage)

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
      packages/certbot/main.py", line 121, in _get_and_save_cert lineage = 
      le_client.obtain_and_enroll_certificate(domains, certname)

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
      packages/certbot/client.py", line 405, in obtain_and_enroll_certificate
      cert, chain, key, _ = self.obtain_certificate(domains)

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/client.py", line 348, in obtain_certificate
      orderr = self._get_order_and_authorizations(csr.data, self.config.allow_subset_of_names)

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/client.py", line 384, in _get_order_and_authorizations
      authzr = self.auth_handler.handle_authorizations(orderr, best_effort)

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 69, in handle_authorizations
      resps = self.auth.perform(achalls)

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2304, in perform
      http_response = http_doer.perform()

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot_apache/http_01.py", line 76, in perform
      self._mod_config()

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot_apache/http_01.py", line 111, in _mod_config
      for vh in self._relevant_vhosts():

File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot_apache/http_01.py", line 166, in _relevant_vhosts
      " {0}.".format(http01_port))

PluginError: Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.
```

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: i can't copy since it from PuTTY terminal.

Comment: Sorry, I got banned in asking question, they told i need to edit this question, but i already did that 3times, and still been banned, how do i supposed to do ? @MartinPrikryl

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important line of the error output is the last. It tells you, that certbot can't find a vhost listening on port 80. I assume you're using Apache Webserver. Make sure you have configured your server correctly.

Maybe also post your apache config, to get further help if needed.

Comment: sorry i am newbie in this , could u tell me exactly what i need to do

Comment: to get more help please post you apache config